# What does "viewed n times" mean

Tags: support, view-counter

Sometimes my question gets viewed 100 times, but still no answer, does viewed count unregistered users too?

Comment: Yes. But unregistered users can still _answer_, it's only asking questions that registering is required for. [Well, and voting of all kinds.]

Comment: Sometimes a car crash gets viewed 100 times, but no one gets out of his/her car to make repairs.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, "views" counts unregistered users too, it does also count as multiple views, repeated visits (some time apart) by the same user(s). It even counts *you* viewing your own question. And, likely also bots and other critters crawling around the internet all day long.

Details can be found here: [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated)

The main point though is that for some questions there might just be nobody that is able and willing to answer it. Reasons for this are be multifold. For general advice on how to frame your questions to increase the chance of getting an answer see: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question